# getting Images from website in python - 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, web

Here is my program and what I need is to collect png extention images from website and save then according their names. Here is the code :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import re

webpage = urlopen('http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/web/12-best-places-to-get-free-images-for-your-site-624818').read()
patFinderImage = re().compile('<img src="(.*)png" />')

filename = ("D:\test\test.json")
imgUrl = re.findall(patFinderImage, webpage)


print("now-----")

actually_download = False

if actually_download:

         filename = imgUrl.split('/')[-1]
         urlretrieve(imgUrl, filename)
      #   fileName = basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
         data = open(filename,'wb')
         data.write(data)
         data.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joh\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272249\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1738, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Users\joh\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272249\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1355, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\joh\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272249\pysrc\_pydev_execfile.py", line 38, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) #execute the script
  File "C:\Users\joh\workspace\new2\url2.py", line 15, in <module>
    imgUrl = re().findall(patFinderImage, webpage)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: By the way, this line imgUrl = re().findall(patFinderImage, webpage) is not in your source code which you pasted, are use sure that traceback comes from this version?

Comment: imgUrl = re.findall(patFinderImage, webpage) me too using this line even i tried re().findall(patFinderImage, webpage) but it generates this error: imgUrl = re().findall(patFinderImage, webpage) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Problem is, that you that code which you pasted is not corresponding to the traceback which makes helping you more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in this line:

```
imgUrl = re().findall(patFinderImage, webpage)
```

Since re is a module not function it should be:

```
imgUrl = re.findall(patFinderImage, webpage)
```

But later you have another error.

Correct code is (I added *.decode("utf-8")*) - the content from read() is of type bytes so you need to convert it to a string before trying to decode it into a json object..

```
import re

from urllib.request import  urlopen
from urllib.request import  urlretrieve

webpage = urlopen('http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/web/12-best-places-to-get-free-images-for-your-site-624818').read().decode("utf-8")
patFinderImage = re.compile('<img src="(.*)png" />')

filename = ("/tmp/test.json.")
imgUrl = re.findall(patFinderImage, webpage)


print("now-----")

actually_download = False

if actually_download:

         filename = imgUrl.split('/')[-1]
         urlretrieve(imgUrl, filename)
      #   fileName = basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
         data = open(filename,'wb')
         data.write(data)
         data.close()
```

Comment: imgUrl = re.findall(patFinderImage, webpage) me too using this line even i tried re().findall(patFinderImage, webpage) but it generates this error:

imgUrl = re().findall(patFinderImage, webpage)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: I pasted you working code. Mark the answer as a working one starring it - if it solves your problem.

Comment: I just run after the changes but now getting this error:
 webpage = urlopen('http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/web/12-best-places-to-get-free-images-for-your-site-624818').read.decode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: You need be more careful during copy paste - you missed again something. Error which you paste is from:
webpage = urlopen('...').decode("utf-8")
but you need webpage = urlopen('...').read().decode("utf-8") (you missed the "read()").

Comment: Now it works.. thank you but not saving any images in file why it is like this?

Comment: data.write(data) - you are trying to write file descriptor itself instead of your real data.

Comment: I changed to data.write(imgUrl) but still no result.